# Screen stops responding in full screen applications

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, graphics, gaming

Hi I am encountering a strange problem any ideas would be helpful.

I am trying to run certain games in full screen whilst doing so my screen goes blank and get the no data received message. This occurs on all games using full screen. However if I play on windowed mode it is not a problem..

Additionally I am using a dual screen set-up. Whilst loading a full screen game the second screen has no issues but the one showing the game does.

Hardware:-

gtx 660
Samsung sync master monitor (2233)
OS: win7

Any ideas would really help.

Comment: It would be useful to know what graphic card and version of driver do you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution,

My screen is having problems displaying above 60hz refresh rate, applications were trying to display above 60hz as the monitor should support up to 120hz however not able to. Used a different screen and had no issues.